# In JavaScript how do I loop through an array and add those elements to an empty object as keys?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

So let's say I have an array and an empty object

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
let obj = {}
```

I'm trying to loop through the array, and add each element of that array as a key to the object with a value of 0. How do I do that? I've tried:

```
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    for (let key in obj) {
      key = array[i]
      obj[key] = 0
    }
  }
```

The output I'd suppose I'd like to get is something like

```
console.log({obj})

{a: 0, b: 0, c: 0, d: 0, e: 0, f: 0}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`for (let key in obj)` doesn't make any sense because the object is empty originally - that will never iterate at all. Use

```
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    obj[array[i]] = 0;
  }
```

Or, more functionally, create the object all at once by mapping the array into an array of entries:

```
const obj = Object.fromEntries(array.map(
  prop => [prop, 0]
));
```

Comment: thanks! this really helps

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce()` like so:

```js
const array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];

const obj = array.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr] = 0;
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(obj);
```

[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: oh wow this is pretty dope too, didn't know I could do such a thing :O